# paragraph in span in paragraph changing html when inserted using .html() function

Tags: jquery

Here is some test code  that illustrates the issue.

```
var $html = '<p>Hi <span class="some-class"><p>Tester</p><p>test2</p></span></p>';

console.log($html);
var obj = $('<div>').html($html);

console.log(obj.html());
```

The output of the first 'log' call is

```
<p>Hi <span class="some-class"><p>Tester</p><p>test2</p></span></p>
```

As expected, but the second one comes out as

```
<p>Hi <span class="some-class"></span></p><p>Tester</p><p>test2</p><p></p>
```

The example is simplified for posting here, but in the application content 'html' is not under my control, and is coming in as a single string. 
I have also tried using .append($(html)); This has the exact same issue.

Comment: It's because you can't nest `<p>` inside `<p>`. It's invalid markup. Browser rejects it and moves things around to correct invalid nesting

Comment: So, given my situation, my best answer would be to strip out '<p>' and replace '</p>' with '<br />'? I kinda don't like that idea. I feel like doing that will result in unexpected errors down the line. Can anyone think of a better answer?

Comment: Best thing is get the source fixed. Could replace `<p>` tags with `<div>` but semantics aren't the same

Comment: I think I like replace p with div better then my BR answer. At least that way if there are class or style tags in the p tag I can preserve them.

Comment: Right... the <br> idea is a bit sketchy